# Inline Visualforce formula error. Syntax error. Found 'IF'

Tags: visualforce, formula

I'm getting the error: `Syntax error.  Found 'IF'`

In my controller I have a `Map<Id,String>` which is working fine. In my page I have the following:

`<apex:column value="{!IF((myMap[case.myField__r.Id]!=null),myMap[case.myField__r.Id],'')}" headerValue="My Heading"/>`

I have done this, because the Map get might return null. Why am I getting this error?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think if the IF returns false your column's value parameter will be blank. That is not allowed so maybe you can change it to this

```
<apex:column>
     <apex:facet name="header">My Heading</apex:facet>
     <apex:outputText value="{!IF((myMap[case.myField__r.Id]!=null),myMap[case.myField__r.Id],'')}" />
</apex:column>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also use `headerValue` attribute instead of  column's header facet as below.

```
<apex:column headerValue="My Heading">
    <apex:outputText value="{!IF((myMap[case.myField__r.Id]!=null),myMap[case.myField__r.Id],'')}"/>
</apex:column>
```